# In bash script, is it possible to echo something into the beginning of file?

Tags: bash, file, shell, echo

I know by

echo text >> file.txt

I can append the "text" to the end of the file file.txt

But is it possible to insert something at the beginning of the file without removing the existing content?

Thanks,

Comment: No; regardless of what technique you might use, it is essentially identical to `{ echo text; cat file.txt; } > new_file.txt && mv new_file.txt file.txt`. The only change you can make to a file without disturbing the existing contents is to add data to the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do it via sed:

```
sed -i '' '1i\
some-text
' file
```

OR using awk:

```
awk -v T=some-text 'NR==1{print T} 1' file
```

Without any external utility:

```
echo -e "some-text\n$(<file)" > file
```

Comment: `sed -i` still creates a temporary file, then moves it into place over the old file. Your third example won't work, or at least will only work if `$(< file)` completely reads the contents of file before it is truncated by `> file`.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks I know sed creates a temporary file and then moves it over. But why is that a concern since all OP wants is to insert some content before 1st line.

Comment: @chepner ... wow, really?  Will `> file` really truncate the stream after some arbitrary limit? i.e. drop what's being sent to it?

Comment: @Ajax There's no arbitrary limit; `> file` *completely* truncates the file before *anything* else is written to it. The problem here is that it's not well defined whether the shell process `$(<file)` to read the entire file into memory before `> file` truncates it.

Comment: My understanding was that a `> redirect` will truncate it _once per defined process_... Example, `exec > >( grep -v "blah" | tee > some_file)` will redirect all stdout to the tee, which will truncate the first time it writes, but then continue appending.  I thought maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4):

You can use cat and a temporary file:

`echo 'text' | cat - file.txt > temp && mv temp file.txt`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ed`, the standard editor:

```
stuff="this is the stuff you want to prepend to file"
ed -s file.txt < <(printf '%s\n' 1 i "$stuff" . wq) > /dev/null
```

If you have several lines to add, put them in an array, like so:

```
stuffs=( "this is the first line you want to prepend to file" "lalala the second line" "my gorilla loves bananas in this third line" )
ed -s file.txt < <(printf '%s\n' 1 i "${stuffs[@]}" . wq) > /dev/null
```

The only limitation is inserting a line that only consists of a single period. Sigh.

`ed` is the standard editor. This method involves no temp files! if you choose this method, you'll genuinely be editing the file (so you won't change permissions and ownerships). It's probably one of the most efficient methods. A more efficient method (used for huuuuge files) is to deal directly with `dd`. But you certainly don't want that here.

As Georgi Kirilov suggests in the comments below, you can use this method without any bashisms as so:

```
stuffs=( "I love oranges, but my gorilla loves bananas" )
printf '%s\n' 1 i "$stuff" . wq | ed -s file.txt > /dev/null
```

provided your system comes with a `printf` (and very, very likely it does).

Comment: Your solution would beat the others on some archaic systems with no GNU around (bash's `$(<)` and sed's `-i`), but the `<()` syntax is still bash I believe.
Something like the following would be even more 'standard':
`printf "1\ni\n${stuff}\n.\nwq\n" | ed file.txt`

Comment: @GeorgiKirilov Yep, I like bash's syntax. Will add your suggestion to the answer, though. Thanks.

Comment: When you are writing to a file that you do have write permission in a directory that you do not have permission to create a temp file, ed is usable while sed simply is not.